# XML: Substitute block as 'variable'

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, logback

I have a logback configuration xml file and what I want to do is to create two appenders which are exactly the same except for filename. e.g.:

```
<appender name="app1" class="c">
   <encoder> 
      <pattern> My pattern </pattern> 
   </encoder>
   <file> file 1 </file>
</appender>

<appender name="app2" class="c">
   <encoder> 
      <pattern> My pattern </pattern> 
   </encoder>
   <file> file 2 </file>
</appender>
```

Is there a way for me to do an 'xml variable substitution so that the `<encoder>` block is same in both appenders?

```
   <encoder> 
      <pattern> My pattern </pattern> 
   </encoder>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could declare an *entity* for the `encoder` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration [
  <!ENTITY encoder "<encoder><pattern> My pattern </pattern></encoder>">
]>
<configuration>
  <appender name="app1" class="c">
    &encoder;
    <file> file 1 </file>
  </appender>
  <appender name="app2" class="c">
    &encoder;
    <file> file 2 </file>
  </appender>
</configuration>
```

Still some repetition (of the `class="c"`, for example) but not as much.

Comment: So while this works in principle (when my "MY pattern" is simple), for logback, the My pattern string has % in it and there are some issues with parsing that. 'date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n'. This would solve part of my problem, and I'll search around for a solution to this issue. 
Error: he parameter entity reference "%message;" must end with the ';' delimiter. 
Thanks.

Comment: @user247077 you can represent the percent sign as a character reference `&#x25;`, e.g. `date - [&#x25;level] ....`  or if that's too long then declare another `<!ENTITY p "&#x25;">` and then use `&p;`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. OTOH, I just realized that I accidentally gave you a downvote on this question. Sorry but I'm not able to change it now. :(